# .NET - TextWriterTraceListener, file in use by another process

Tags: .net, exception, logging

I'm creating a trace listener like this:

```
// Setup log tracing.

Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(MyLogPath));
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "-" + " Program started");
```

When I detect the file has got too large, I'm wanting to truncate it (or rather, take the last N lines only).  In order to do this, I want to read the file in, but it seems no-matter what I do the trace listener has a lock on it, i.e. trying to remove the trace listener and dispose of its stream like this:

```
// Clear logging.

Trace.Listeners[0].Close();
Trace.Listeners[0].Dispose();                     
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
```

, before reading it in like this:

```
// Read in existing log.

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyLogPath);
```

, gives me an IO exception (file is in use by another process).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the reason you can't re-open the file once it's opened by the TraceWriter is because it opens it with a Share Mode of 'Read' (per Process Monitor). That share mode means you can't re-open it (create a new handle) with write access.

However, closing the TraceListener *does* close the underlying stream. The problem is likely that you are closing the wrong listener.

Don't forget that there is always a DefaultTraceListener created at process launch unless you explicitly remove it.

So the correct version of your code should be:

```
Trace.Listeners[1].Close();
Trace.Listeners[1].Dispose();
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
```

Comment: Ah!  Yes, I just discovered this after inspecting the collection.  This works.